# How to watch detail information about error in JavaFX WebView executeScript()?

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, webview

I'm getting nervous about this question. I have a WebView based code editor writed in JavaFX. When i'm calling some JavaScript code from Java by

```
webEngine.executeScript("editor.doSomething();");
```

end having some JS error in method `doSomething()` this call makes an exception
`Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" netscape.javascript.JSException: Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8`

And this exception tells nothing about that happened in what line!

Can i somehow get this information in `webEngine.executeScript()` calls? Thanks!